# vue-chartjs and custom legend using generateLegend()

Tags: vue-chartjs

The generateLegend() wrapper does call the legendCallback defined in my Vue code but I'm lost to how to render the custom HTML in vue-chartjs. What do I do with htmlLegend as described in the vue-chartjs api docs like [here](https://vue-chartjs.org/api/#generatelegend).

Here is the line chart component I'm trying to render with a custom HTML object.

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['chartData','options'],
  data: () => ({
    htmlLegend: null
  }),
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
    this.htmlLegend = this.generateLegend();
  }
}
```

Here is my vue template

```
<template>
            <div class="col-8">
                <line-chart :chart-data="datacollection" :options="chartOptions"></line-chart>
            </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `htmlLegend` holds the markup of the generated legend... so you can just put it into your tag via `v-html`

```
<template>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="your-legend" v-html="htmlLegend" />
    <line-chart :chart-data="datacollection" :options="chartOptions"></line-chart>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mounted() {
    this.renderChart( this.chartData , this.options );
    var legend = this.generateLegend();
    this.$emit('sendLegend', legend)
}
```

and then in the vue file add a new div to show the legend and also listen to the event to get the legend data

```
<div class="line-legend" v-html="chartLegend"></div>
<line-chart @sendLegend="setLegend" :chart-data="datacollection" :options="chartOptions"></line-chart>
```

and also add this to the data

```
   chartLegend: null,
```

and you also need a method

```
    setLegend (html) {
        this.chartLegend = html
    },
```